# Force a segue in an unwind

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `storyboard A` with a list of buttons and a counter with the amount of buttons that I have. Every time I press one of those buttons, the counter decrease and you segue to `storyboard B`. In `storyboard B` there is a `return` button with and `unwind` to `storyboard A`.

What I want to do is, when the `counter` reach `0`, segue to `storyboard C`.

What I have tried is, in the controller of `storyboard A` I added:

```
@IBAction func unwindToStoryboardA(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let sourceViewController = segue.source as? StoryboardBController {
                currentButtonPressed?.isHidden = true
                counter -= 1
                // If there are no more buttons, segue to storyboard C
                if counter == 0 {
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "StoryboardCsegue", sender: self)
                }
        }
    }
```

But, what is actually happening is, it goes to `storyboard C` but immediately return to `storyboard A`. Why is this?

Is there another way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segue is not finished when you reach `unwindToStoryboardA`, so you can't perform the next segue from there.

Instead, set a property `whereToNext` to hold the identifier, and then use it in `viewDidAppear` to segue to the next ViewController:

```
var whereToNext: String? 

@IBAction func unwindToStoryboardA(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = segue.source as? StoryboardBController {
        currentButtonPressed?.isHidden = true
        counter -= 1
        // If there are no more buttons, segue to storyboard C
        if counter == 0 {
            // set whereToNext, the actual segue is now in viewDidAppear()
            whereToNext = "StoryboardCsegue"
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // unwrap whereToNext if there is a value
    if let identifier = whereToNext {
        // set it back to nil so we don't go there more than once
        whereToNext = nil

        // segue to the next ViewController
        performSegue(withIdentifier: identifier, sender: self)
    }
}
```